# FreeDOS USB drive does not show in option key boot menu on Macbook Pro (Late 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, partition, dual-boot

I've been struggling for two days to dual-boot FreeDOS along with Mac OS X on an old MacBook (late 2011)  that I have.

- I've tried doing the live CD option and flashing it to the drive with Rufus.
- I've tried following the instructions on the FreeDOS website for the USB drive and copying the contents of the .img file to the disk.
- and I've tried using Boot Camp which gives me an error that the Windows installer isn't found.

Nothing works. Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?